# createContext/ useContext in React not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, use-context

Can't understand why my use of `createContext` and `useContext` is not working in my React application.

I have my context file like so:

```
// @flow
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export type CountryIndexProviderType = {
  index: number,
};

const CountryContext = createContext<CountryIndexProviderType>({
  index: 0,
});

type CountryContextProviderProps = {
  children: Node,
  index: number,
};

const CountryContextProvider = ({
  children,
  index,
}: CountryContextProviderProps) => {
  return (
    <CountryContext.Provider value={{ index }}>
      {children}
    </CountryContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useCountryIndexContext = () => useContext(CountryContext);

export { CountryContext, CountryContextProvider, useCountryIndexContext };
```

And my component where I am using `Provider` to set the value of `index` (number):

```
import { CountryContextProvider } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";

return (
 {objects.map((index) => (
  <StyledWrappingContainer>
    <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
    <CountryContextProvider index={index}>
    // NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?
    </CountryContextProvider>
  </StyledWrappingContainer>
 ))}
);
```

And my second component, where I am using `useContext` to pass the value of `index` to a styled component and render the value:

```
import { useCountryIndexContext } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";
const { index } = useCountryIndexContext();

<StyledWrappingContainer>
   <StyledProgress>
      <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
   </StyledProgress>
</StyledWrappingContainer>
```

The second component is always rendering the default index value of 2 (default index = 0 + 2 added in render) - can anyone suggest why my `index` value is not being updated?

Comment: please provide valid component definitions, not just incomplete snippets. Where are you updating the `index` and where is it defined?

Comment: updated to include how the index is passed into the component. this basically indicates how many times this component is rendered. (repeating component depending on users definition of how many times they want to add a country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values from context after wrapping them inside the Provider.

In here:

```
  return <CountryContext.Provider value={{ index }}></CountryContext.Provider>;
```

The Provider doesn't have any children, so index is never transfering to another component.

I suggest you use `children` prop.

```
    const CountryContextProvider = ({ index,children }: CountryContextProviderProps) => {
  return <CountryContext.Provider value={{ index }}>{children}</CountryContext.Provider>;
};
```

Finally pass any component that you want to use index from context, as children of `CountryContextProvider`:

```
    import { CountryContextProvider } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";

return (
 {objects.map((index) => (
  <StyledWrappingContainer>
    <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
    <CountryContextProvider index={index}>
<YourSecondComponent /> /// can have any props it needs, not necessary.
</CountryContextProvider>
  </StyledWrappingContainer>
 ))}
);
```

Now the `YourSecondComponent`, where you receive index.

```
   import { useCountryIndexContext } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";
const { index } = useCountryIndexContext();


    <StyledWrappingContainer>
       <StyledProgress>
          <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
       </StyledProgress>
    </StyledWrappingContainer>
```

Comment: hey Erfan - thanks for your comment. I've updated the question code to reflect your comments. In the first component should I be passing the child component into the ContextProvider? if so does it need props?

Comment: You need to pass Your second component as child. it can have its props, but it's not necessary. I updated my answer. @cts

Comment: thanks. one thing I'm a little confused about is that when I try to render my second component inside of the context provider of the first. It complains on runtime about missing properties of undefined (in the child component) - but surely we don't want to pass it props as we don't want to actually render that component (but just ensure it has access to index?). will keep playing with it - thanks for the help though!